# How to set username and password for our own docker private registry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was able to run repository using `$docker container run -itd --publish 5000:5000 registry` But, I am not asked for username and password when I pull or push the image to that repository.

How to set username and password for our own docker private registry and how to use them in Dockerfile and docker-compose when we want to use the image from that repository?

Answer (score 8):

> How to set username and password for our own docker private registry?

There are couple ways to implement basic auth in DTR. The simplest way is to put the DTR behind a web proxy and use the basic auth mechanism provided by the web proxy.

To enable basic auth in DTR directly? This is how.

1. Create a password file containing username and password: `mkdir auth && docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn your-username your-password > auth/htpasswd`.
2. Stop DTR: `docker container stop registry`.
3. Start DTR again with basic authentication, see commands below.

Note: You must configure TLS first for authentication to work.

```
docker run -d \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

---

> How to use them when we want to use the image from that repository?

Before pulling images, you need first to login to the DTR:

```
docker login your-domain.com:5000
```

And fill in the username and password from the first step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use self-signed certificates for running the private registry?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created the local private registry. Then if I want to pull images from private registry  using  Dockerfile or docker-compose, where should I mention registry's username and password?

Comment: step 1 gives this error: `docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "htpasswd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.`

Comment: @birgersp registy:2 is broken, use registry:2.7.0 instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531462/docker-local-registry-exec-htpasswd-executable-file-not-found-in-path

Answer (score 1):

Use `httpd:2` instead of `registry` for generating the password:

```
docker run \
  --entrypoint htpasswd \
  httpd:2 -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

see: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#native-basic-auth