# docker local registry "exec: \"htpasswd\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Until recently this worked fine

```
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn myuser  mypwd  > /my/registry2/reg/hub/auth/htpasswd
```

now its erroring out with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"htpasswd\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

this is on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 with docker

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.11
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        42e35e61f3
 Built:             Mon Jun  1 09:12:22 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       42e35e61f3
  Built:            Mon Jun  1 09:10:54 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It will continue to work if you pin the local docker registry to

```
registry:2.7.0
```

instead of picking up the latest version 2 by just using `registry:2` which is sadly broken

for details see  https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image/commit/ab00e8dae12d4515ed259015eab771ec92e92dd4 (they removed package apache2-utils)  and   https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/pull/2538/commits/f816c837e34eb389c2cdee1bc9a2918c5d2e33e3   and  https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/pull/2539 as referenced in https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image/issues/106

alternatively, instead of executing htpasswd from inside registry:2  you can install binary htpasswd using

```
apt-get install apache2-utils # thankfully this is NOT the apache server
```

and use syntax

```
htpasswd -Bbn myuser  mypwd  > /my/registry2/reg/hub/auth/htpasswd
```

on Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04

PS here are all files which come from package apache2-utils ... just some utilities not any server

```
dpkg -L apache2-utils 

/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/ab
/usr/bin/checkgid
/usr/bin/fcgistarter
/usr/bin/htcacheclean
/usr/bin/htdbm
/usr/bin/htdigest
/usr/bin/htpasswd
/usr/bin/logresolve
/usr/bin/rotatelogs
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/check_forensic
/usr/sbin/httxt2dbm
/usr/sbin/split-logfile
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/apache2-utils
/usr/share/doc/apache2-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-utils/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/ab.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/htdbm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/htdigest.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/htpasswd.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/httxt2dbm.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/logresolve.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/check_forensic.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/checkgid.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/fcgistarter.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/htcacheclean.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/rotatelogs.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/split-logfile.8.gz
```

for good measure I booked docker a ticket on this https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/11060

Comment: PlusOne for "thankfully this is NOT the apache server"

Answer (score 4):

The current [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#native-basic-auth) describes a simple way to generate a secret with htpasswd:

```
 mkdir auth
 docker run \
  --entrypoint htpasswd \
  httpd:2 -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

The newly generated file `auth/htpasswd` can later be used in the registry image:

```
docker run -d \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v "$(pwd)"/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue [Docker registry with native basic auth not working](https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image/issues/106). It appears they removed `htpasswd` due to some CVEs, so installing the binary could make your container less secure. You might want to track this issue until they come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `htpasswd -B` from `apache2-utils` packages.

Example.: `htpasswd -B -b passwordfile username password`

> Docker requires the password to be hashed using the bcrypt algorithm,
> which is why we pass the -B parameter. The bcrypt algorithm is a
> password hashing function based on Blowfish block cipher, with a work
> factor parameter, which specifies how expensive the hash function will
> be.

Comment from: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-top-of-digitalocean-spaces-and-use-it-with-digitalocean-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in my Dockerfile and now things are fine again.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache apache2-utils
```

So my Dockerfile now looks as follows.

```
FROM registry   

RUN apk add --no-cache apache2-utils

RUN mkdir /auth \
    && htpasswd -bnB admin admin > /auth/htpasswd
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate an encrypted password using pearl crypt function:

```
perl -le 'print crypt("my-password", "my-salt")'
```

This will output an encrypted password string. Copy and Paste the encrypted string in the `/path/.htpasswd` file such that

```
username:encrypted-password
```